# Move one digit to make the equation $62-63=1$ true

Tags: mathematics

This mathematical statement is obviously false. Move one digit to make it true.

> $$62-63=1$$

Comment: I was just trying to post a simple puzzle. Apparently these are bad.

Comment: It's not bad. It's not the best puzzle you could have posted either, but it's fun. Have a +1 from me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Exponentiation will help! 
>  
>  Move the 6 so that, 
>  $2^6 - 63 = 1$

Answer (score 3):

I can make it true by moving a single line:

> $62 = 63 - 1$

Comment: But a line isn't a digit...